# Arch Linux - dhcpcd messages at login screen

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, arch-linux

I have a fresh installation of Arch Linux, and I've enabled `dhcpcd` on `eth0`. However, the message output for `dhcpcd` startup appears after the OS is booted up and is at the login screen, so I get this:

[image: Arch Linux booted showing dhcpcd messages after the login screen]

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's been a bug I have seen for a while.  I just hit enter, and then it allows you to login.  My guess is you will be setting up a login manager along with X, so in the future after that you won't even see it.

Comment: No, not really; I am intending to run this as a server of various sorts with minimal overhead.

Comment: @GeorgeK. Can you show us how long it takes for `dhcpcd` to start? the output from `systemd-analyze blame` ? On my computer it takes 7 seconds or so (really long time for my standards) yet I see no messages on top of the login prompt. Also as a remedial solution, you can add `quiet` to your kernel line on you bootloader.

Comment: Running `systemd-analyze blame` spits out the following: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/systemd-analyze", line 23, in <module> from gi.repository import Gio ImportError: No module named gi.repository`.

I'm assuming that I don't have the `gi` module installed?..

Comment: Understood, that makes sense. Though the other services should be up in the background anyway. I'm surprised that you're using a rolling release system as a server. But arch is pretty great.

Comment: @GeorgeK. yeah you need to install python2-dbus and python2-gobject for systemd-analyze.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Here's the output: http://i.imgur.com/dK60sUv.png

Answer (score 0):

By default, `getty@.service` is of type "idle", which means it'll be started only when systemd's job queue empties for the first time. Unfortunately, the conditions for turning off the status display are not *quite* the same – the latter happens only when default target starts, but the job queue often runs empty before that.

On slower systems, another cause for this might be that "idle" has a timeout of two seconds, after which getty is started *anyway*, even if the system is still booting.

As a workaround, you can make getty's service unit tell systemd to turn off status display immediately. Copy the following to `/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service`:

```
.include /usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/kill -s RTMIN+21 1
ExecStopPost=/bin/kill -s RTMIN+20 1
Type=simple
```

Comment: Didn't work: kernel panicked; had to restore previous snapshot

Comment: If changes to systemd units cause a kernel panic, you're making the wrong changes.

Comment: Ok, I did two things. I first created `/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service` and put in the changes above, and that didn't fix it. I then saw that there was a `getty.target.wants` folder under the same directory, and there was a `getty@tty1.service` in there, and appended the lines above to that file, and that's when the kernel panicked and I had to roll back. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@.service on the line which starts with After=...

Change it to: After=multi-user.target

or: After=graphical.target